# Primefaces selectManyCheckbox: Can't make checkboxes dynamic with respect to each other

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm trying to have 3 checkboxes (a,b & c) in a group where if b is selected, a is also automatically selected. But when I am using the `valueChanbgeListener` argument, it is only giving me the information of the `selectedItem` list before committing the most current change to the list. Also, this change needs to be reflected in the front end as well - which means I have to update the `ui-component` after the backing bean `handleChange()` method's work is done.

JSF XHTML code:

```
<h:form id="form" >
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" /> 

    <h:panelGrid> 
        <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{superUser.selectedOptions}" 
                              layout="pageDirection" 
                              onchange="submit()" 
                              valueChangeListener="#{superUser.handleChange}">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{superUser.allOptions}" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />

    <p:dialog header="Selected Values" 
              modal="true" 
              showEffect="fade" 
              hideEffect="fade" 
              widgetVar="dlg">  
        <p:outputPanel id="display">
            <p:dataList value="#{formBean.selected}" var="item">  
                #{item}
            </p:dataList>  
        </p:outputPanel>  
    </p:dialog> 

</h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean (name="superUser")
@ViewScoped
public class SuperUserBacking implements Serializable {    
    ...
    ...

    private HashMap<Integer, String> monthMap;

    private Map<String, String> allOptions;
    private List<String> selectedOptions;

    public void initializeEventCopyFunction(){
        initializeCheckList();
    }

    private void initializeCheckList(){
        allOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        allOptions.put(this._RACE, this._RACE);  
        allOptions.put(this._COLUMNS, this._COLUMNS);  
        allOptions.put(this._MESSAGE, this._MESSAGE);
        allOptions.put(this._STAFF, this._STAFF);
        allOptions.put(this._EQUIPMENT, this._EQUIPMENT);
        selectedOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void handleChange(){
        LOGGER.info("handleChangeMethod Called");
        if(selectedOptions==null)
            return;

        System.out.println("\n");
        for(String selected : selectedOptions){
            System.out.println("Selected : "+ selected);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
   }
  //GETTERS AND SETTERS
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem completely, but try to replace all this: `onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{superUser.handleChange}"` with  `<p:ajax listener="{superUser.handleChange}" update="(id of components to update)" />`. Put this p:ajax just below the f:selectItems. Maybe the handleChange()-method needs an AjaxBehaviourEvent as parameter, I don't remember

Comment: @Jaqen H'ghar Thanks so much! This works exactly the way I needed it to work. Now I can dynamically toggle checkboxes in the backing bean.